# Many programs reading single XML Java

Tags: java, xml, saxparser, domparser

My program uses a SAX parser (or maybe DOM parser) to read from an XML file located somewhere on a server. Now many people use my program, so many programs sometimes access this one XML file. Can there be problems if e.g. two users (which are using my program at the same time) want to read (only read and not write) the XML file at the same time? Do I have to consider anything special in my program or will this be handled by the OS?

Unfortunately I am not familiar with simultaneous access to files or if several people use my program and such a siutation occurs.

The program is built with Java 11.

Comment: If they are not writing, it should not cause any issues (apart from being slower if many people access the same file at once).

Comment: @assylias Is right, no problem if the operation Is read only. For better performance try caching the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shouldn't cause a problem. It's not necessarily the most efficient way of doing it but for a low-throughput application it should work perfectly well (we have an in-house application that handles about 10 requests per day and this is exactly how we do it.)

If you decide to be a bit more ambitious and cache the parsed document in memory, you need to be aware that the default DOM implementation in Java is not thread-safe - even for read-only access. That's one of the reasons why I advise people to go with a third-party tree model such as JDOM2 or XOM.

Comment: This means that if two users each on their local machine are using my program and they want to access the document at the same time (i.e. want to read the XML document - meaning with the DOM parser), then this can lead to problems because they cache the parsed document? Or am I getting you wrong?

I can make sure that in the same program all this is thread-safe, but I can't react to the other user's program because they both use a separate deployed instance of my program. That's why I asked if the access from file (via DOM) is controlled by the operating system.

Comment: If they're loading separate instances of the program accessing filestore independently and not sharing memory, then yes, they'll both have to parse the file and there's no scope for sharing anything except the file on disk. If you want to scale up to hundreds of users and dozens of transactions per second, then that's not the optimum architecture; you should implement the application within an HTTP server and let the users connect to it remotely.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the advise!